# How to check what the data type is being used?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have an assignment in which one of the methods of class creates a tree node of generic type T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if an object reference is an instace of a specific class there is the infix operator [`instanceof`](https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator). You can use that in an if-else-statement to handle the three different cases.

```java
Object data = treeNode.getData();
if (data instanceof LinkedList) {
    LinkedList list = (LinkedList)data;
    // do stuff ...
} else if (data instanceof CircularArray) {
    CircularArray array = (CircularArray)data;
} else {
    // error state - throw excpetion or handel this case someother way
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For any TreeNode object `treeNode`,

```java
treeNode.getData() instanceof LinkedList
```

will return `true` if the `dataItem` is an instance of LinkedList. Same goes for CircularArray.